# Set display of an element and set a cookie to keep it hidden on click

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm looking for a simple way to hide an element and set a cookie to keep it hidden on click.

```
<div id="hide-me">I need to be hidden</div>

<div id="hiding">
 If I get clicked, #hide-me's display style goes from block to none.
 Now the next time this person visits again, #hide-me will be display:none.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nECXV/1)

```
var COOKIE_NAME = "hideMeDisplay",
    hideMe = document.getElementById('hide-me'),
    cookie = getCookie(COOKIE_NAME),
    hideMeDisplay = cookie  ? cookie : hideMe.style.display,
    hiding = document.getElementById('hiding');

hiding.onclick = function() {
    setCookie(COOKIE_NAME, hideMeDisplay, 100);
    hideMe.style.display = hideMeDisplay === "block" ? "none" : "block";
    hideMeDisplay = hideMe.style.display;

}
hiding.onclick(); // trigger first click to set cookie
```